# 3.5 hours in and still cannot install Django - my fortitude is waning

Tags: python, django

Hi and thank you for taking time out of your day to read this, and I very much appreciate any assistance.

I'm trying to install Django for the first time - on a mac, python 3.7.7. However, the packages seem to be looking for 2.7 which is not the intended v3.

I understand the best practice is to install this via a virtual environment. I am currently following this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment). Installed the package via `sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper`

When I run `mkvirtualenv my_django_environment`
I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 585, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 598, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'zipp>=0.4' distribution was not found and is required by importlib-resources
```

I've tried this `mkvirtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 my_django_environment`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3241, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3225, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 585, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 598, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'zipp>=0.4' distribution was not found and is required by importlib-resources
```

Running `vim ~/.bash_profile`

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Django
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Any guidance would be most appreciated!

I previously tried to install virtualenv via `easy_install -m virtualenv` Could there be some confusion?

Comment: It seems an dependency issue with pip. First try running `pip install -U pip` and then first uninstall `sudo pip3 uninstall virtualenvwrapper` after that again install `sudo pip3 install virtualenvwrapper`. Also there is another package for virtual environment, you can try [this one](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html).

Comment: If you're using Pycharm, it can config the vent itself. Anyways, try to install the latest python, and then use `python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment`

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug many thanks for your response. when I run sudo pip install -U pip I get the following error. sudo: pip: command not found Should I change it to pip3?  Or was your pip suggestion, due to seeing 2.7 errors?

Comment: @dimButTries yes, you should change it to `pip3` my bad I forgot to put 3 over there.

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug regrettably following those three steps yields the same error msg. Could this be due to the command disregarding me pointing it to python 3 and instead of loading resources from python 2.7? Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Yes, I guess it is taking python 2.7. Do you have 2 distributions of python ?

Comment: @dimButTries you can follow this tutorial for virtual environment. I personally use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html) distro, but this should work (after all virtual environments just provide a dependency management container), [give it a try](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-django-on-mac-or-linux)

Comment: Even if I run virtualenv -p python3 user/Django/test I still get the same error. Is there a way to rebuild the python 2.7 errors, or can I force it to look at python3?

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug going to give up. I followed the tutorial and post successful installation typing pipenv into the terminal yields -bash: pipenv: command not found.  Many thanks for helping - it is most appreciated. I might try to uninstall everything and perhaps use brew instead.

Comment: Don't give up. yes it will be a good idea to remove both python distributions and then install only python 3.

Answer (score 0):

My must earnestly confess I do not know why my set up did not work.

However, I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@adarshvc/how-to-install-python-3-django-and-create-a-virtual-environment-on-macos-e5cbda4c6356) which used brew and `python3 -m venv`. I then carried on installing Django and it worked great.